# Global Instance Variable in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an array, `@genres`, that I get from querying a database on my sinatra server. I use this genres list to populate a dropdown menu in my navbar. I want this list to be available for each page I go to, and I also want the list to update each time, in case a new genre was added to the db in between page loads.

Obviously I could add code that runs the SQL query and populates the `@genre` variable for every `get`, `post`, and `delete` method, but that seems like a lot of repeated code. Is there a more elegant way to create a variable common to all sinatra http methods?

Comment: Why don't you take the time to add some sample code, instead of asking us to imagine all of it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a before filter:

```
before do
  @genres ||= Genre.all # or however you access the array
end
```

If you want to omit `put` requests from having the variable, define a condition for that:

```
set :method do |method|
  condition do
    method.include? request.request_method.downcase.to_sym
  end
end
```

Then you could do something like:

```
before :method => [:get, :post, :delete] do
  @genres ||= Genre.all
end
```